# How to allow a sandboxed Assembly to load certain types?

Tags: c#, sandbox

I have made a sandbox class which I use to invoke methods in untrusted code. I want the untrusted code to be able to implement an interface and be able to access certain help classes. This is how I load the assembly:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
assembly.GetTypes();
```

Calling **GetTypes()** will throw a **ReflectionTypeLoadException** with the loader exception set to a **TypeLoadException**:

> "Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member foo. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden."

How can I setup my sandbox environment to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding a member with the `[SecurityCritical]` attribute? If you are loading a non-public, transparent (partially trusted) assembly then this exception will be thrown if you try to override a `SecurityCritical` member.

For more information about Security-Transparent code, see [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102.aspx) article. The upshot is that transparent (partially-trusted) code cannot call into security critical code. See in particular this section:

In this section, the following order is assigned to Transparent, Critical, and SafeCritical code based on access and capabilities:

> Transparent < SafeCritical < Critical
>
> - Rules for types: Going from left to right, access becomes more
>     restrictive. Derived types must be at least as restrictive as the base
>     type.
> - Rules for methods: Derived methods cannot change accessibility from
>     the base method. For default behavior, all derived methods that are
>     not annotated are Transparent. Derivatives of critical types cause an
>     exception to be thrown if the overridden method is not explicitly
>     annotated as SecurityCritical.

In particular the second bullet point.